# Two variables display as 0 in debugger, but subtracting gives -5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, math, lldb

In this code, an answer of 0 would be correct, but I'm ending up with -5. So why is this simple arithmetic calculation wrong? What might have happened?

```
int daysFromCurrentDay = (i-(1 - weekDisplay));

// daysFromCurrentDay shows as 0 in the debugger.
// currentDay shows as 0 in the debugger.

daysFromCurrentDay -= currentDay;

// daysFromCurrentDay now shows as -5... What??
```

Comment: It's easy to prove your assertion `0-0 = -5` is false so unless you can post more context, I'd say this is likely due to user error with the debugger.

Comment: @Alan it's set a couple of lines before it, and not set anywhere else in code.

Comment: Hmmm just changed from LLDB to GDB, and currentDay now shows as 5 instead of 0. Not sure what is going wrong with LLDB, but at least now I can debug the problem and fix it.

Comment: What are the types and values of `i` and `weekDisplay`? It's really impossible for someone else to figure this out as is, but at first glance it looks like something's unsigned and you're having overflow issues.

Comment: LLDB had, maybe still has, a bug with display of ivars. Make sure you're using the latest version.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau they're both unsigned. Thanks, I might be using an old version so that's probably the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing from LLDB to GDB temporarily fixed this... not sure why LLDB was showing an incorrect value, but problem solved for now.